# MainViewController init

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have set up a utility application and I found that the init method of MainViewController is not called automatically. Is there some other method that is set up automatically by XCode for initialization?  Or if I have to add it, where would I add it?  I was just going to call init manually from an IBOutlet method but I would prefer that the initializations be done when the view is first initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you'r going but (generated) .xib files are called using the withCoder init.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) 
    {
        //self implementation
    }
    return self;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Utility Template in Xcode.
And check this method called..

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

check it..